# Erro ao excluir registro com Entity Framework quando faço o mapeamento da entidade

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, repository, automapper

Quando tento excluir um registro a partir do mapeamento do `Mapper` (Model to Domain) tenho o seguinte erro como retorno do `E.F`:

> failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

Porém se faço uma pesquisa usando o `ID` informado na `Model` e uso o resultado para excluir o registro, sem fazer o mapeamento, a operação ocorre normalmente.

Trecho do código que gera erro:

```
  //aplicação
  public void Delete(MinhaModel modelo){  

     var entidade = Mapper.Map<Entidade>(modelo);

     _meuRepository.Delete(entidade);
  }

 //repositório
 public void Delete(T entity){

     Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

     Context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);

     Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;

     Context.SaveChanges();

}
```

Trecho do código que funciona:

```
   //aplicação
   public void Delete(MinhaModel modelo){  

         var entidade = _meuRepositorio.ObtenhaPorId(modelo.Id);

         _meuRepository.Delete(entidade);
      }

    //repositório
     public void Delete(T entity){

         Context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

         Context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);

         Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;

         Context.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Minha dúvida é porque o erro ocorre quando eu tento excluir o registro usando o retorno do `Mapper` ?

Comment: Para o Entity possa realizar qualquer operação de GRUD o objeto precisa está no contexto por isso que o segundo trecho de código funciona, pois certamente o seu método ObtenhaPorId faz _context.Entidade.Find(id); E no primeiro trecho de código o seu objeto ainda não está mapeado para o contexto. 

Ps.: Gostaria de te dá uma explicação mais técnica, mas infelizmente não sou especialista no Entity.

Answer (score 0):

> Minha dúvida é porque o erro ocorre quando eu tento excluir o registro usando o retorno do Mapper ?

Quando você carrega os objetos do banco de dados com o Entity Framework, esses objetos são salvos em cache por referência. Então, quando você tenta dar attach na entidade, o EF primeiro irá procurar nesse cache, quando você dá um mapping, a referência do objeto é outra (mesmo o ID sendo o mesmo, então o EF acredita que você está tentando salvar um outro objeto com um ID que já existe), e quando você dá o findById ele também procura primeiro no cache (por isso funciona, a referência do objeto é a mesma).

Você pode remover a entidade do banco de dados substituindo o código

```
Context.Set<T>().Attach(entity);
Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

por:

```
Context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
```

Ou, se não quiser salvar no cache as entidades, use o método AsNoTracking().